# Serialize an object array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have this object array:

```
array (size=[...])
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2382]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2383]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  [...]
```

How can I serialize it to `1, 2, [...]`?
I tried with `implode(', ', $array)` but as it is an object it returns `CATCHABLE FATAL ERROR: OBJECT OF CLASS STDCLASS COULD NOT BE CONVERTED TO STRING`

Comment: Why not `serialize($yourobject);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not quite *serialize* things (this term usually refers to converting object instances to a binary form) but rather *map* each element (object) to its id and then concatenate these ids.

You can do that with:

```
$ids = array_map(function($obj) { return $obj->id; }, $array);
echo implode(', ', $ids);
```